# past participle + ing Vs present perfect + ing

Tags: gerunds, ing

What is the difference between past participle + ing and present perfect + ing? For an example: If you **started playing the game**, you should have noticed the issue. Vs If you **have started playing the game**, you should have noticed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The word "playing" in those examples is actually a gerund, the direct object of "started" (as @BillJ points out, "started" is a [catenative verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs)).

The difference in conjugation is between the simple past and present perfect tense of "started." Past tense ("if you started") implies an action that took place and completed at some point in the past.

On the other hand, present perfect tense ("if you have started") refers to a past action that continues to the present or has a connection to the present ([PEG](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-perfect-or-past-simple.html)). In this instance, saying that you "have started the game" would imply that you are still playing the game.

Comment: I disagree. "Start" is a catenative verb, and "playing the game" is not its Od but its catenative complement. Objects are virtually always noun phrases, but "playing" is a verb with "the game" as its Od.

Comment: It is a [catenative verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs), yes, but the direct object is a NP headed by a verbal (gerund or to-infinitive).

Comment: "Playing the game" is a clause, not an NP. The head is "playing", the Od is "the game", and the semantic (understood) subject is "you".

Comment: "You started [you] playing the game"? What if I said instead, "you started *to play* the game"? Or "you *like* playing the game"? Or simply "you started the game"?

Comment: Most non-finite clauses have no overt subject, but we understand them as though they have a subject. The obvious 'understood' subject of "playing " is "you", The same applies to the infinitival "to play the game".